# How many times can you reheat fudge

Tags: candy

I made fudge. It did not set. Recipe left out crucial info: how long at soft ball stage? Cool slightly before beating? How long do you beat it? And how many times can it be "remade" or cooked before starting over?

Comment: Please try to narrow this down to just one question, if you can. StackExchange tries not to handle multi-question questions, to make it easier for people to search for the information they want.

Comment: Hey hey. I think the question in your title could stand on its own and is interesting, but the questions in the body have been discussed here: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/51839/fudge-not-setting-up-any-salvaging-possible-alternate-uses/51856#51856